# Set start offset for a repeating animation only for start

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to put some delay for starting of an animation. So, when an animation is not going to repeat, we can easily use `startOffset` property. The thing is I have an animation which is going to repeat infinitely. But I have to start it with a delay, so when I use `startOffset`, the animation always repeat with that delay which is not what I want. Also I don't want to use `Handler` for creating delay.

**EDIT:**

I have never used ObjectAnimator. My code is like below but it doesn't animating. What is my mistake?

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 1000, -1000);
objectAnimator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
objectAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
objectAnimator.setStartDelay((5 - i) * INTERVAL);
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.play(objectAnimator);
animatorSet.start();
```

Comment: `Also I don't want to use Handler for creating delay` - why?

Comment: Because the animation will be assigned to many Views and anywhere in the middle of everything I have to remove all animations. So, if I use handler then I have to remove callbacks for every view.

Comment: then use `AnimatorSet` with an offset playing normal repeating animation - i think this should work

Comment: I will test it.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: ok so i checked that and it seems that you dont even need `AnimatorSet`: normal `ObjectAnimator` works just fine with a starting offset and some repeating count - it just delays at start and when reaping there is no delays between repetitions

Comment: I can verify, that @pskink's solution works.

Comment: so whats your code?

Comment: Sorry, I thought first that he is pointing to your first solution. I edited my question.

Comment: first solution works as well but is more complex

Comment: `ObjectAnimator repeat = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0, 360);
        repeat.setRepeatCount(4);
        repeat.setDuration(1000);
        repeat.setStartDelay(2000);
        repeat.start();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156332/discussion-between-a-badakhshan-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink, It worked. So put an answer if you want so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VectorDrawable and AnimatedVectorDrawable in XML files in res/drawable folder and defined your animation in an objectAnimator file in res/animator folder then the startOffset delay works on the first occasion only not during repetitions. Repetitions are immediate. On the other hand if you want the animation to start with the delay everytime it repeats then I believe onAnimationEnd resetting works.